# Django substr / substring in templates

Tags: python, django, templates, substr

Could someone tell me, does the method like substr in PHP (http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) exist in Django templates?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the [`slice` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice), though I don't think there's an equivalent to the `$length` argument.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `cut` filter e.g. :

```
{{ value }} -> 'hello world'
{{ value|cut:'hello ' }} -> 'world'
```

Answer (score 5):

In python, substrings are accessed as slices; there's a built-in [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice) filter in django.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone felt leaving a link would be enough, I'll add some code sample from [django documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) here:

`slice` filter returns a slice of the list

```
{{ some_list|slice:":2" }}
```

If *some_list* is `['a', 'b', 'c']`, the output will be `['a', 'b']`.

Answer (score 1):

See **truncatechars**, [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) filters:

```
<p>Example {{ person.names|truncatechars:20 }}</p>
```